# What could be the reason my module is not working

Tags: php, xml, magento, nginx

I tried 20 times probably ,with Apache ,with nginx ,on windows ,on ubuntu ,followed millions of tutorials and books and still the same thing ,I a getting really frustrated so please help. All I want is simple hello world in the browser.I have the following structure.First is MasteringMagento_Example.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config>
    <modules>
    <MasteringMagento_Example>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
    <depends />
    </MasteringMagento_Example>
    </modules>
</config>
```

My structure is MasteringMagento/Example and there are the Block,Model,controolers ... folders .In the etc config.xml is the following :

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MasteringMagento_Example>
            <version>0.0.0</version>
        </MasteringMagento_Example>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <example>
                <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Model</class>
            </example>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <example>
                <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Block</class>
            </example>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <example>
                <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Helper</class>
            </example>
        </helpers>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
        <example>
        <use>standart</use>
        <args>
            <frontName>example</frontName>
            <module>MasteringMagento_Example</module>
        </args>
        </example>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

And in controllers folder file HelloController.php :

```
<?php

class MasteringMagento_Example_HelloController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction(){
        echo 'hello';
    }
    public function worldAction(){
        echo 'hello world';
    }

}
```

when I type magento.local/example/hello/world ,I am getting :

Whoops, our bad...

The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.

```
    If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
    If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.
```

Whoops, our bad...

The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.

```
    If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
    If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.
```

What can you do?
    Have no fear, help is near! There are many ways you can get back on track with Magento Store.

```
    Go back to the previous page.
    Use the search bar at the top of the page to search for your products.
    Follow these links to get you back on track!
    Store Home | My Account
```

I am running ubuntu with nginx as server ,the magento.local is working it loads the starting page ,but after that nothing is working ,please help me ,what could be the reason ,I am really frustrated 
What can you do?
    Have no fear, help is near! There are many ways you can get back on track with Magento Store.

```
    Go back to the previous page.
    Use the search bar at the top of the page to search for your products.
    Follow these links to get you back on track!
    Store Home | My Account
```

Comment: Do you have a closing tag for your PHP and XML? Also, that is a lot of code to print "Hello World" on the screen. I would fix the php syntax first then roll-back on all the extra code until it starts to work. PHP alone can print "Hello World" on the screen, so something is blocking your php.

Comment: I want to load module in Magento ,I know php can print hello world ,but I am trying to learn magento ,which is working with custom modules and xml configurations.The problem is not in the closing php tag ,its something else a lot more complicated.I am stuck on this s*it bug all day

Comment: Try localhost/magento/example/hello/world. All browsers understand the url shortcut 'localhost'. If your running a localhost server it is the only way your browser will allow access to internal pages. I do not think this is the full answer or even a partial one, but the browser should respond.

Answer (score 0):

I would say because you wrote standart instead of standard.

Michele

Comment: The OP has several boo-boos to fix.